# Gaussian Process Regression prior with observations as integrals?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, gaussian-process, nonparametric-regression

Consider some standard 1d Gaussian Process Regression (GPR). Suppose you are not happy with a typical mean-zero prior away from the data and you actually want something like the derivative of the mean to be zero (away from the data).

I think one way of getting at this is to start by modelling the observations as coming from *the integral* of the mean zero Gaussian Function.

So $Y_t = \int_0^t X_s \text{d}s + \text{noise}$ and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ being the GP.

Does this setup make sense? Can you simply calculate the integral of the GP to get the kernel for the observations (still a GP I think).

This is basically what is doen for observations of the derivatives ... so this is simply observations of the integral.

What happens with the unknown constant appearing in the integral of the kernel?

UPDATE: I should link to this nice post on GPR with derivative observations for reference.

http://herbsusmann.com/2020/12/01/conditioning-on-gaussian-process-derivative-observations/

Comment: Yes I see no reason why this wouldn't work. Can you be more precise about what unknown constant you're referring to?

Comment: @JohnMadden I mean that when I vaguely say "the observations are an integral of the latent GP" I think there appears a constant of integration that we need to deal with in the kernel. i.e. when we calculate $\text{cov}(Y_t, Y_t')$ and do Fubini or whatever it is called.

Comment: Oh I see. I suspect this can simply be dealt with using a constant mean function. If you find a nice and simple closed form for the kernel integrals, please let me know! Personally, I have just used computer algebra (mathematica) to compute closed form solutions, but they're not pretty :)

Comment: @JohnMadden I'm not sure 100% but I think it's more subtle than simply using a constant mean function ... for example consider data generated from a piecewise constant function that you observe sparsely. If you simply use a mean and any standard kernel, you will have "dips" in your inferred mean. I think the key might be to ensure the kernel comes from a martingale for this problem. In higher dimensions it gets more complicated and I do not have clear ideas yet.

Comment: I think I see what you mean regarding your formulation of the problem, regarding the means you suggest. But regarding the ends outlined in your initial paragraph, do note that a GP which reverts to a constant away from the data is the same as a GP that reverts to zero derivative away from the data, right?

Comment: @JohnMadden I guess I was being ill-defined a bit in my question ... am thinking more about some kind of martingale. Consider even a Brownian kernel min(t, s) ... I suspect simply integrating BM several times will give reasonable kernel for this kind of flat Martingale extrapolation.